# She was trapped and was shot or she was trapped and shot

Tags: passive-voice

I'm a little bit confused in the situation where we use two verbs in a passive voice sentence. So, should we omit the to be verb there or keep it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: May I ask why you chose that example in particular?

Comment: It's just a spontaneous thought. I didn't remember the original sentence, just the problem

Comment: They are not simultaneous: She was trapped, then shot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two homogeneous predicates in your sentence (***was trapped*** and ***was*** ***shot***).

As the structures of these predicates are the same the second common auxiliary (***was***)  can be omitted.

According to the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20trapped%20and%20shot%2C%20was%20trapped%20and%20was%20shot%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20trapped%20and%20shot%3B%2Cc0) there is only one way of saying: "...was trapped and shot".